# Tableview Inserting Rows Jumpy

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, load

I have implemented the insertRows method in my table view. If I'm scrolling down or at the bottom of my tableView contents while the tableView inserts new rows, the whole table acts jumpy and places me in a different location in my tableview's content. How do I fix this? I have added my code at the bottom:

```
//Method to load more data
func loadMoreFeed() {
    let rowsBefore = self.tableObjects.count
    loadMoreFeedInBackground() { queryObjects in
        for object in queryObjects! {
            self.tableObjects.append(object)
        }

        self.tableObjects.sort {
            $0.date!.compare($1.date!) == .orderedDescending 
        }

        let rowsAfter = self.tableObjects.count
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

        for i in 0 ... (rowsAfter - rowsBefore - 1){ //start i at zero and go up to the difference - 1
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: rowsBefore + i, section: 0)) //insert an index path in the array
        }

        self.isMoreDataLoading = false
        self.loadingMoreView!.stopAnimating()

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }            
}
```

Method Of when to load new objects

```
var isMoreDataLoading = false
var loadingMoreView : InfiniteScrollActivityView?

/* Loads more feed while scrolling */
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (!isMoreDataLoading) { //is not loading more

        // Calculate the position of one screen length before the bottom of the tableview
        let scrollViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
        let scrollOffsetThreshold = scrollViewContentHeight - tableView.bounds.size.height

        //start loading more data after user went 4/5 of the way through the content
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > 4*scrollOffsetThreshold/5 && tableView.isDragging) {

            isMoreDataLoading = true //set loading data to true

            // Update position of loadingMoreView, and start loading indicator
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: InfiniteScrollActivityView.defaultHeight)
            loadingMoreView?.frame = frame
            loadingMoreView!.startAnimating()
            loadMoreFeed()

        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using footer for every row?

Answer (score 0):

for Method Of when to load new objects this is my implementation

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
  let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
  let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
  if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
    // print("this is the last cell")

    if (!isMoreDataLoading) { //is not loading more
      // start loading indicator
      loadMoreFeed()

      // Update position of loadingMoreView, and 
      loadingMoreView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: InfiniteScrollActivityView.defaultHeight)
      loadingMoreView!.startAnimating()

       self.tableView.tableFooterView = loadingMoreView
       self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
    }
  }
}
```

for updating tableView this is my implementation

```
private func updateTableView() {
  let rowsBefore = self.tableObjects.count
  loadMoreFeedInBackground() { queryObjects in
  for object in queryObjects! {
    self.tableObjects.append(object)
  }

  self.tableObjects.sort {
    $0.date!.compare($1.date!) == .orderedDescending 
  }

  let rowsAfter = self.tableObjects.count
  let indexes = rowsAfter - rowsBefore

  guard indexes > 0 else {
    self.isMoreDataLoading = false
    self.loadingMoreView!.stopAnimating()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
    return
  }

  var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
  for index in 0...(indexes - 1) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index + rowsBefore, section: 0)
    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
  }

  if tableView.contentOffset.y > tableView.estimatedRowHeight {
    let initialOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    tableView.setContentOffset(initialOffset, animated: false)
    tableView.endUpdates()

  } else {
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
  }

  //refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```